# How do I add Jupyter to IBM Watson Studio?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ibm-watson

Wherever I look up how to open a notebook, it says to go to the notebook link in the "add to project" window, but I do not see an add notebook option there.  Do I need to download Jupyter, or an add on for Watson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to download jupyter notebook, it is available as feature in watson studio cloud.
Please create a project first 
[image]

and then inside the project, there is an option "Add to Project" to add a notebook inside that specific project.
[image]

Comment: That makes sense, but I don't have notebook as an option.  Is Jupyter available with lite?

Comment: Notebook should be available for Lite Plan of WS. You are probably missing watson studio service in the region where you are trying to access watson studio , for ex. https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com -> US Region Watson studio, https://eu-gb.dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com is for UK Region and so on. The service is used for entitlement purposes, so you need to have Watson studio service in the region to get those notebook and other options(entitlements), please provision one using this https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/watson-studio

Comment: I think you're right.  Now my problem is that IBM cloud won't accept my email.